# Why is my suggested edit still pending review after being approved?

Tags: support

[This](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/212584) suggested edit page says both:

> Your suggested edit is pending review.

and

> [womble](https://serverfault.com/users/1375/womble) reviewed this 5 hours ago: **Approve**

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of suggested edit]

As a new user, I'm left wondering why the edit hasn't gone through, given that it has been approved. I assume there is some criterion about the number of reviewers that must approve, but the page doesn't say anything about that. Am I right? If so, perhaps the page should link to documentation about the review process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It takes more than one person to approve a suggested edit. Here on SF I believe it requires 2 people to approve or reject an edit to get a final decision. You only have one. When the folks from Europe wake up I'm sure you'll get a decision.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it would be something like this, but couldn't find documentation. Do you have a link? And do you think the page itself should include that link?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/help/editing